# Failed to save mail attachments using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I try to save attachments using applescript, my script works well when the files are small (e.g 109 Bytes) but save empty file when the attachment is too large (304KB). I'm working on macOS High Sierra and had no clue how to fix it, anyone got any idea?

My acript:

```html
using terms from application "Mail"
 on perform mail action with messages theMessages

  set myPath to "Macintosh HD:Users:MY_USER:Downloads:"
  tell application "Mail"
   repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
    
    repeat with theAttachment in eachMessage's mail attachments
     set originalName to name of theAttachment
     set savePath to myPath & originalName
     try
      save theAttachment in savePath
     end try
    end repeat
   end repeat
   
  end tell
 end perform mail action with messages
 
end using terms from
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have to check the settings in *Preferences>Accounts>Account Information>Download Attachments*

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I try to change this preference but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It is working for me even with 3mb large files. So I guess the problem lies with your mailbox itself somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322724/156892, change:

```
save theAttachment in savePath
```

to:

```
save theAttachment in file savePath
```

In addition, it would be more robust if you set myPath like so:

```
set myPath to (path to downloads folder as text)
```